# Angular 2 Template driven form with custom input

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have a template driven form with a read only input. When the user clicks on the input, a date picker appears. After the user selects the date, the input field gets populated with the information. However, when I click submit, the data is not there from that input. The other fields work though.  So in this case, I get an output of

Console Output:

> ```
> Object {refNumber: "215170", date: ""}
> ```

HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Reference Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="refNumber">
    </div>

    <!--Date Picker-->
    <input (focus)="toggleDatePicker(true)" readonly value={{date}} class="form-control" formControlName="date" />

    <date-picker *ngIf="showDatePicker" [initDate]="date" (onDatePickerCancel)="toggleDatePicker($event)" (onSelectDate)="setDate($event)"
        ngDefaultControl></date-picker>

</form>
```

Component Code

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

public myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    refNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    date: [''],
    });
}

onSubmit(formOutput: FormGroup) {
    console.log(formOutput.value);
    alert('Submit this data to database')
}

// Date TimePicker
private date: any;
private showDatePicker: boolean;

// Date Pciker
toggleDatePicker(status: boolean): void {
    this.showDatePicker = status;
}

setDate(date: any): void {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

----------Update--------------------------
I have created a new project just to replicate this issue. The problem is still there. Here is a video of what is happening in this project. To me, it looks like the input value only gets updated when I type something in. Any hard-coded value or in this case, the date that gets passed in, does not update the actual input value behind the scene?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xc3m6qbILc

https://github.com/eddy80310/formsissue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `datepicker` is returning a Object which is neither `Date` nor `String` nor does it have a `toString()` defined. Based on the console output, the following change to your `setDate` function should solve the problem.

```
setDate(event: any): void {
    // console.log(event);
    this.date = event.date;
}
```

If this does not solve the problem then uncomment the `console.log` in the function to check the format of `event` object and set the `this.date` value accordingly.

**FINAL EDIT**

Okay.. took me a while on Plunker to figure out the actual problem. You are setting the value on the DOM Element directly. Now the problem with that is, it is not triggering any event for ngModel to know about the change.

Following two solutions for this (tested both & both work):

1. Use `setValue` to change the value of the input textbox. Example `this.myForm.controls['date'].setValue(dateValue)`.
2. Use `ngModel` in your input element. Replace `value={{dateValue}}`
   with `[(ngModel)]='dateValue'`. Since your input element is readonly,
   you could also do unidirectional data binding using
   `[ngModel]='dateValue'`.

I have tested both the solutions on Plunker. Here is the link to the
    [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckVWLMxNVp1XI9XnPNoW?p=preview) with `setValue()` (first option).

Comment: the formate of it does not seem to be the issue. As I have tried to remove all code from setDate() and set private date = "1234". When I do that, I see that the input field does get populated with 1234, however, upon submit, I still see the same output with date being "". I am guessing setting value={{date}} does not work  with the form? I have even tried to hard code value="1234" in the html and the result is the same. However, if I get rid of readony and type things in, the form seems to get that data fine in that case

Comment: There is one more issue. You have the input name as **date** and also the variable in your component is named **date**! So instead if picking up the date value, that is causing the mess up.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed it. Also, please see my previous comment for additional information. Much appreciated of your help

Comment: I have edited my response with the correct solution (for changing the variable name).

Comment: I would actually prefer to change the value using `this.myForm.controls['date'].value` in component code (in the `setDate` function).

Comment: Hi Santanu, I have tried all that. In fact I have created a video illustrating the problem and uploaded a new project with nothing but the issue with the form in the question above.  As shown in the video, it seems like when I type something in, everything works. However, if I use the date picker or in fact the default "1234", the value does not get updated. It should be pretty clear in the video. Cheers

Comment: Can you tell me which date-time picker are you using? I can test it on plunker.

Comment: https://danielykpan.github.io/ng2-date-time-picker/

Side question though.... as shown in the vide, it seems like it is not the picker's problem. Because the initial value "1234" was not registered as well. And when I did pick a date, if I edit in the input, the date actually gets registered

Comment: Found the problem and the solution. See my edit above.

Comment: You sir are very very smart and kind. I have tried both and they do indeed work. Simple. Effective. May I ask if you read up some helpful information somewhere? Or just trial and error?

Comment: I knew that the change is not getting detected. Using Plunker I verified that I was right. Thereafter, the first solution that came to my mind was `ngModel`, but somehow I don't like to mix it with `ReactiveForms`, so the second option was to try [`setValue()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html). You can also play around with `emitEvent` if you still want to set the DOM value directly!